# Search more similar results

Tags: views, search

I created a block of my products with "View" and "Search API". I want to show in this block, the related products using the title of the current page as a keyword. How to do this ? thank you

[image]

Comment: what you want exactly? want to create a block that according to current page title search some nodes by title( get nodes with similar title to current page title)??

Comment: @zhilevan I seen the block search api compares key words of the title of the current page to the bodies and titles of other nodes.

Comment: I want to use the words of the title of the current page as keywords to the block display

Comment: I opened a more detailed post here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207462/search-related-content-of-the-current-page